# Extract equation as text from a screenshot

Tags: input, ocr

Is it possible to snip an equation from pc screen e.g. with windows snipping tool from edge or acrobat and paste it to wolfram math input online or Mathematica, like copy text from picture with Mathpix Snipping tool?

Comment: In windows. key combination  Shift+Windows+S and draw a rectangle copies the image to the clipboard. Can be copied here directly via the image icon. Click the "Paste" link.

Comment: Thanks, and of course then I have the icon snip in the clipboard, but how to get the text of that snip to the command line as text e.g. x^3 + 2x^2+10x=20 ... when I have the image ... as OCR to text?

Comment: TextRecognize[image,Language->{ "Equation","English"}]. As always with tesseract as OCR, exact horizontal text is a must, ImageSize is open to experimets and often MorphologicalBinarize is helpful. But don't expect too much, one needs weeks of experience. The free, opensource,  full tesseract software can be trained on special texts, too.

Comment: Is this an advertisement of "Mathpix Snipping Tool" ?

Comment: @advertisement ... do it feel like? ... i would not advertise... to expensive :)